# Create daily workbook

Tags: macros, tabularx

I would like to use LaTeX for my daily events : (like a `longtable`, etc.)
For the left column I have the date, and the second column contains pre-stored `newcommand`/`newenvironment` setups to call them repetitively (for tables/paragraphs/ figures, etc.). I am using (master/slave) files to classify them by dates in folders.

I tried the `tabularx` merged with `listliketab` but I cannot optimize the code. I get a wrapped table at the bottom. Is there any advised package or solution that can solve the following issues?

- Being able to add macros (`newenvironment`/`newcommand`) inside the listliketab main table.
- Avoid the text wrapping at the bottom of the page
- Table which will take the whole page
- Have the same spacing between events (daily) in the second column.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,openright,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %insertion d'images
\usepackage{lipsum} %paragraphes prédéfinis
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary,listliketab,array,multirow}    
\begin{document}
        \begin{listliketab}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{.5em}} XR}
                03/10/2016 %& \lipsum{1} \\
                & \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                    This & is & a test \\
                    Kinda &   &   \\
                \end{tabular}\\
            \hline
            & The second step \newline 
            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                This & is & a test \\
                Kinda &   &   \\
            \end{tabular}\\
        \hline
        & \begin{itemize}
            \item different content might appear here 
            \item figures ...
        \end{itemize}\\
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{listliketab}
\end{document}
```

Any optimization is welcome. Thank you